# Vector potential of photon in quantum field theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, potential, quantum-electrodynamics, polarization

In quantum field theory the solution to Maxwell's equation is given by:

$$
A^\mu(x)=\underbrace{\sum_{r,\mathbf k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2V\omega_{\mathbf k}}}\varepsilon_r^\mu(\mathbf k)a_r(\mathbf k)e^{-ikx}}_{A^{\mu+}}+\underbrace{\sum_{r,\mathbf k}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2V\omega_{\mathbf k}}}\varepsilon_r^\mu(\mathbf k)a^\dagger_r(\mathbf k)e^{ikx}}_{A^{\mu-}}
$$

(From *Student Friendly Quantum Field Theory*, p. 145)

Here, $\varepsilon^{\mu}_{r}$ is the polarization vector and $r=0,1,2,3$ is being summed over.

My question is: why, for example, can $A_{x}$ have components on the $y$ and $z$ axis?

Comment: This question reduces to "why does a vector field depend on all the space-time coordinates?".

Comment: $\mu$ runs over 0,1,2,3, therefore one has $A^0, A^1,A^2,A^3$,  or in a different notation $A=(\phi, A_x, A_y, A_z)$. A priori $A_x$ has no relation with $A_y$  or $A_z$ (making here no difference between upper and lower indices which is sloppy) . However, for the 4-potential it is problematic that it has actually only 2 degrees of freedom, but 4 components. This is an issue that is discussed often in this context.

Comment: I don't understand why you claim that $A_x$ has components "on the y axis". Can you be more explicit about that?

Comment: @ACuriousMind $\varepsilon^{\mu}_{r}$ are direction vectors, aren't they?

Comment: no, $\epsilon^\mu_r$ is the $\mu$-th *component* of the $r$-th direction vector.